# Changing element on screen width with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, api

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    // Instagram

    if ($(window).width() > 500) {
        var userFeed = new Instafeed({
        get: 'user',
        userId: '00000000',
        accessToken: '00000000',
        limit: 20
    });
    userFeed.run();
    } else {
        var userFeed = new Instafeed({
        get: 'user',
        userId: '00000000',
        accessToken: '00000000',
        limit: 10
    });
    userFeed.run(a);
    }  
</script>
```

Hi, I'm a student webdesign and recently accepted my first project for a friend. I implemented her Instagram into the website but on small screens I need to limit the amount of pictures that come through. I am not good with Javascript nor jQuery. Somehow it only runs the else statement. Any chance I could receive some help/tips?

[www.my-dear.be](http://my-dear.be)

Comment: It would be easier to put the feed in a containing element which you can then amend using a responsive stylesheet, eg: `overflow: hidden` or `scroll`, with a set `height` and `width`

Comment: And exactly whats the problem?

Comment: it's a fixed div with height:100vh so on smaller screens those pictures overlay the next div.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan Thank you that's actually very helpful.